How to guarantee high precision timer on Windows 11, even when the App is fully minimized
The timers on Windows run at a rate of 15.6ms per tick. So, even if you set a timer to 1ms, it still takes 15.6ms to complete (this does depend on exactly when the timer was started, but this is the gist of it).
Using timeBeginPeriod(1) (from the Windows API), you can set this to a higher resolution of 1ms.
Unfortunately, on Windows 11, this resolution increase is not guaranteed if a window-owning process becomes minimized, according to the documentation:

Starting with Windows 11, if a window-owning process becomes fully occluded, minimized, or otherwise invisible or inaudible to the end user, Windows does not guarantee a higher resolution than the default system resolution. See SetProcessInformation for more information on this behavior.

Is there a way to guarantee this higher resolution of the timer on Windows 11 onwards, even when the window is minimized? Or is there an alternative to timeBeginPeriod() that can achieve this resolution?
The reason I am asking:
We want to start polling some high precision instruments at an interval of 1ms over a serial port and collect that data, even when the application that is polling is minimized.
Interesting notes:

It doesn't have to be exactly 1ms, 1.342ms is also fine, but it should be around there, and not the default timer resolution of 15.6ms.
We are using C# and WinUI for the interface
Polling is done off the main thread
Yes, we are using timeEndPeriod to stop it. :)

I have been looking around for any information on this, but have not found any more details that can shed light on this.

Wrong opreating system. Windows is not a real-time OS, and any thread may take longer than 1ms (or much longer than that) to be scheduled, and can be interrupted at any time. Use a real-time OS if precision is paramount, or get the device to poll itself and buffer the results.

^^ Maybe a PLC might even be a better choice than "forcing" Windows to be much more precise than it can be. Not to start with the dotnet runtime on top of that.

15.6 ms is the default resolution but you can change it (especially if you own the whole machine). It's in fact a complex matter, I recommend reading Bruce Dawson's blog about this https://randomascii.wordpress.com/tag/time-resolution/

"We" achieved "precision timing" by having our (custom heat treating) devices do their sampling (recording) "on board" to memory. The "app" would then retrieve the samples from the device's memory. In that way, we could also "restart" the sample downloads. Depending on the sampling rate, the device could sample for days or weeks or more before "wrapping". At a fixed rate, all samples have their own "slot" in the device's memory for a given start time.

"We want to start polling some high precision instruments at an interval of 1ms over a serial port" - Correct me if I'm wrong, but serial-ports on PCs (regardless of OS) are an interrupt-driven device, so you can't meaningfully "poll" a serial-port. (While you can epoll/poll a serial-port in Linux+BSD, that isn't the same thing as a low-level hardware poll - for that you'd need a sampler or protocol-analyzer tbh...)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter might help

@Charlieface Fortunately it doesn't have to be that precise that a real-time OS is required. It will also have to run on client PCs so there are a lot of things to take into account here. The important part of this question is an option to work around the new Windows 11 limitation here that it simply doesn't respect the new timer resolution if the window is minimized.

OK well I agree QueryPerformanceCounter is a good start, also maybe use a separate service to do the polling. "Polling is done off the main thread" why would you do that, it would be much better on a separate thread.

Off the main thread, means "not on the main thread". Yes, it's on a separate thread.
I am not sure what to do with QueryPerformanceCounter in this case. It gives me precise timestamps, but it's not a timer.
Is your idea to use this to write my own timer which runs on the CPU instead and never sleeps?

You could try to use QPC/QPF.

@Jeaninez-MSFT How could I use QPC/QPF to have a timer go off every 1ms when Windows reduces the resolution from 1ms back to it's default 15.6ms?

The frequency of the performance counter is fixed at system boot and is consistent across all processors. As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to use QPC/QPF to have a timer go off every 1ms.

@Jeaninez-MSFT exactly, so why are people suggesting it? What I want is that timeBeginPeriod(1) properly sets the timer resolution to 1 ms (approximately, when possible) and not suddenly set it back to 15.6 when the app is minimized.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182958/windows-11-application-timing-becomes-uneven-when-backgrounded

Well, as the timeBeginPeriod documentation now says, we need to use SetProcessInformation and explicitly disable PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_IGNORE_TIMER_RESOLUTION.
To use it in .NET, we need to write some minimal wrappers. (I'm translating it on the fly from VB.NET in which I had to write and test it, so treat it as a basic illustration).
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class WinNative
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll"]
    public static extern UInt32 timeBeginPeriod(UInt32 ms);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SetProcessInformation(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        int ProcessInformationClass,
        IntPtr ProcessInformation,
        UInt32 ProcessInformationSize
    );

    // From processthreadsapi.h (for Win11+); we define only those used
    private const int ProcessPowerThrottling = 4;
    private const UInt32 PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_IGNORE_TIMER_RESOLUTION = 4;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE
    {
        public UInt32 Version;  // ULONG
        public UInt32 ControlMask;
        public UInt32 StateMask;
    }

    public static int DisableThrottling(IntPtr? hProcess = null)
    {
        var sz = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE));
        var PwrInfo = new PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_STATE() {
            Version = 1,
            ControlMask = PROCESS_POWER_THROTTLING_IGNORE_TIMER_RESOLUTION,
            StateMask = 0 };  // disable that flag explicitly
        var PwrInfoPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sz);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(PwrInfo, PwrInfoPtr, false);
        if (!hProcess.HasValue)
            hProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess.Handle;
        var r = SetProcessInformation(hProcess.Value, ProcessPowerThrottling, PwrInfoPtr, sz);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(PwrInfoPtr);
        return r ? 0 : Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        // Note: prior to Win11, the above should return code 87 (invalid parameter).
    }

}

Now, when you need it, you call WinNative.timeBeginPeriod(1) as before, and also WinNative.DisableThrottling() (optionally with the required process handle - by default it will use the current process). Presumably, in any order. When done, just timeEndPeriod(1) should suffice.

I ran a quick test today and this does seem to work. Brilliant, thanks.
Marked as the answer.

I've used the QPC (QueryPerformanceTimer) functions to get highly accurate measurements of performance performance. The .NET functions are probably easier to use, but I have used it, for example, to check display frame rate very accurately which is important in my applications. You do have to used LARGE_INTEGER data... it's not the easiest thing to work with, but it's a much better measurement then the 16ms timer which is useless for performance data. This also, of course, is in a Win32 SDK desktop application.
Here's the link to the MS documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps

We don't need measurement but scheduling. So this answer doesn't help with this unfortunately.

You don't need to go down to P/Invoke level operations to use high precision timers, and in fact you shouldn't. You already have .Net primitives built to allow this:

Stopwatch will always use high precision timing data, though of course it's not an event driven object, it's a query object (ie, you ask it for time).
PeriodicTimer is the .Net 6+ async timer implementation and will always use the highest available precision to trigger its awaitable continuation.
And the most controllable solution is to simply have a thread busy-wait and keep polling DateTime.Now until you get the precision you want. This solution is much, much more reliable since you don't relinquish your thread, and thus don't need to rely on the task scheduler to give it back to you in time.


This is quite irrelevant to the question, you can use any .NET timer you want, if Windows resolution is 15.625ms (use clockres from sysinternals to determine it for example), a PeriodicTimer(1ms) will tick around 16ms.

*"since you don't relinquish your thread, and thus don't need to rely on the task scheduler to give it back to you in time." - That would be correct, for Windows 1, 2, or 3. Those systems rely on cooperative multitasking. Win9x and Windows NT use preemptive multitasking. Just because your thread is busy spinning doesn't mean that it cannot be preempted by the OS.

But it does mean that it's far less likely to happen than if you relinquish it yourself.
